# fast way to put ones beetween ones in each row of a numpy 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix

I have a 2d array (Q) consisting of just zeros and ones. I wish to fill with 1 each position between 1's of each line Q. Here's an example:

**Original matrix:**

```
[0 0 0 1 0 1]
[1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 0 1 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 1]
[0 1 1 0 0 1]
[1 0 1 0 1 0]
```

**The resulting matrix:**

```
[0 0 0 1 1 1]
[1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 0 0]
[1 1 1 1 1 1]
[0 1 1 1 1 1]
[1 1 1 1 1 0]
```

I implement an algorithm, it works, but for large arrays it is not efficient.

```
def beetween(Q):
    for client in range(len(Q)):
        idStart = findIdStart(Q, client)
        idEnd = findIdEnd(Q, client)
        if idStart != idEnd and idStart > -1 and idEnd > -1:
             for i in range(idStart, idEnd):
                  Q[client][i] = 1
     return Q

def findIdStart(Q, client):
    if Q.ndim > 1:
        l, c = np.array(Q).shape
        for product in range (0, c):
            if Q[client][product] == 1:
                return product
    else:
        idProduct = 1
        Qtemp = Q[client]
        if Qtemp[idProduct] == 1:
            return idProduct
    return -1

def findIdEnd(Q, client):
    if Q.ndim > 1:
        l, c = np.array(Q).shape
        Qtemp = Q[client]
        for product in range(0,c):
            idProduct = (c-1)-product
            if Qtemp[idProduct]==1:
                return idProduct
    else:
        idProduct = 1
        Qtemp = Q[client]
        if Qtemp[idProduct] == 1:
            return idProduct
    return -1
```

I'm trying to build a more optimized version, but I'm not having success:

```
def beetween(Q):
    l, c = np.shape(Q)
    minIndex = Q.argmax(axis=1)
    maxIndex = c-(np.fliplr(Q).argmax(axis=1))
    Q = np.zeros(shape=(l,c)).astype(np.int)
    for i in range(l):
        Q[i, minIndex[i]:maxIndex[i]] = 1
    return Q
```

**Original matrix:**

```
[0 0 0 1 0 1]
[1 0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0 0]
[1 1 0 1 0 0]
[1 0 0 0 0 1]
[0 1 1 0 0 1]
[1 0 1 0 1 0]
```

**Wrong Result**

```
[0 0 0 1 1 1] # OK
[1 0 0 0 0 0] # OK
[1 1 1 1 1 1] # wrong
[1 1 1 1 0 0] # OK
[1 1 1 1 1 1] # OK
[0 1 1 1 1 1] # OK
[1 1 1 1 1 0] # OK
```

Can anybody suggest another simple solution to this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Thank gentlemen, all the proposed algorithms solved the problem elegantly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
In [25]: Q
Out[25]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])

In [26]: np.maximum.accumulate(Q, axis=1) & np.maximum.accumulate(Q[:,::-1], axis=1)[:,::-1]
Out[26]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Or

```
In [36]: np.minimum(np.maximum.accumulate(Q, axis=1), np.maximum.accumulate(Q[:,::-1], axis=1)[:,::-1])
Out[36]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

In either case, the two terms being combined are

```
In [37]: np.maximum.accumulate(Q, axis=1)
Out[37]: 
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

and

```
In [38]: np.maximum.accumulate(Q[:,::-1], axis=1)[:,::-1]
Out[38]: 
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `np.apply_along_axis`:

```
import numpy as np

def minMax(A):
    idx = np.where(A == 1)[0]
    if len(idx) > 1:
        A[idx.min():idx.max()] = 1
    return A
​
np.apply_along_axis(minMax, 1, mat)

# array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
#        [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
```

Answer (score 1):

The function below looks at a single row and fills 1s between other 1s if they exist.  It assumes that the array contains only 0s and 1s.

```
import numpy as np

def ones_row(row):
    if np.sum(row) >= 2:  # Otherwise, not enough 1s
        inds = np.where(row == 1)[0]
        row[inds[0]:inds[-1]] = 1
    return row
```

Now you can process your entire array with

```
for jj in range(len(Q)):
    Q[jj] = ones_row(Q[jj])
```